# Loading images from a list on Android Wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm new to java and Android Wear. I've been learning over the last few days to make a watch face. I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1

I have a list of images to load in an integer array

```
ImgFileIDs[0] = R.drawable.background
ImgFileIDs[1] = R.drawable.hour_hand
ImgFileIDs[2] = R.drawable.minute_hand
ImgFileIDs[3] = R.drawable.second_hand
```

I want to iterate through the list and read all the bitmaps using this

```
for (int i=0; i<nImages; i++){
  Drawable backgroundDrawable;
  backgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(ImgFileIDs[i], null);
  TempBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
  Imgs.add(TempBitmap);
}
```

This fails with...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4410012 byte allocation with 1504948 free bytes and 1469KB until OOM

however replacing the i index in ImgFileIDs[i] with ImgFileIDs[0]

```
  backgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(ImgFileIDs[0], null);
```

this runs... but obviously I can only access one image. Any hints?

**Edit:**
So it appears that the images are being loaded in at a greater size than the source image.

[image: debug info]
Screenshot from Android Studio

The debug info says the image is 700x700... yet the source file is only a 400x400 32bit png.

Why is it allocating more memory than necessary to the bitmap images?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to use images that are smaller in size; it seems you are using images that are very large in size (i.e high resolution); remember that on a watch, resolution is not that high, so you should be able to easily create images that are much smaller so you don't run into OOM.

Comment: They are quite small. I can read them all in manually and add them to the vector absolutely fine without memory issues.
If I copy'n'paste the code within the for loop nImages times, use getDrawable(R.drawable.xxxxxx, null); and add them all outside a loop it works fine.

Comment: Then maybe your for-loop itself is being executed multiple times? Based on the info that is provided and the fact that images are small, there is not much one can suggest to help you with your issue.

Comment: Well I found the problem but not the solution. The images are 600x600 .png files... however, when debugging, the Bitmap width and height are reported as 1050x1050 (wtf?) So it looks like the images were too large sort of...